# Ember template not rendering correctly after adding model data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

There's probably something really dumb that I'm missing...

After adding the fixture data to the areas route, the 'areas' template won't render.  Everything outside of a template still renders fine.  If I comment out the line where I return data to be passed in as the model (i.e. '//return this.store.find('gamearea', 1);'), everything renders as expected, minus the fixture data, obviously.  When the template doesn't render properly, Ember doesn't throw any kind of error either.

Eventually, I'll replace the divs inside gamearea entirely with game-zone components. I'm sort of in an in-between stage at the moment.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Here's the relevant code:

EDIT: The code is slightly outdated, best bet would be to go to the jsbin here:

[jsbin.com/jomema/1/edit?html,css,js,output](http://jsbin.com/jomema/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
//my areas route:

Areas.Router.map(function () {
 this.resource('areas', {path: '/'});
});

Areas.AreasRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function () {
  return this.store.find('gamearea', 1);
 },
 
 actions: {
  drawCard: function () {
   var $cards = $("#lib1").children();
   $("#hand1").append($cards[0]);
   var cards = this.store.all('card').filterBy('location', 'lib1');
   console.log(cards.objectAt(0).get('location'));
   cards.objectAt(0).set('location', "hand1");
   console.log(cards.objectAt(0).get('location'));
   
  }
 }
});

//the fixture data and model definitions:

Areas.Card = DS.Model.extend({
 name: DS.attr("string"),
 img: function() {
  return ("http://mtgimage.com/card/" + this.get("name") + ".jpg");
 }.property("name"),
 domid: function () {
  return ("card"+this.get("id"));
 }.property("id"),
 location: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: "lib1"})
});

Areas.Gamearea = DS.Model.extend({
 zones: DS.hasMany('zones', {async: true})
});

Areas.Zone = DS.Model.extend({
 name: DS.attr('string'),
 cards: DS.hasMany('cards', {async: true}),
 zone: DS.belongsTo('zone')
});


Areas.Zones.reopenClass({
FIXTURES: [

 {id: 1, name: 'lib1', cards: [1,2,3,4,5]},
 {id: 2, name: 'lib2', cards: [6,7,8,9,10]}
 ]

});
Areas.Cards.reopenClass({
FIXTURES:  
[  
  {
   id: 1,
   name: "Island",
   zone: 1
  },{
   id: 2,
   name: "Jace, the Mind Sculptor",
   zone: 1
  },{
   id: 3,
   name: "Island",
   zone: 1
  },{
   id: 4,
   name: "Counterspell",
   zone: 1
  },{
   id: 5,
   name: "Island",
   zone: 1
  },
  {
   id: 6,
   name: "Island",
   zone: 2
  },{
   id: 7,
   name: "Jace, the Mind Sculptor",
   zone: 2
  },{
   id: 8,
   name: "Island",
   zone: 2
  },{
   id: 9,
   name: "Counterspell",
   zone: 2
  },{
   id: 10,
   name: "Island",
   zone: 2
  }
]
});
Areas.Gamearea.reopenClass({
FIXTURES: 
{
 id: 1,
 zones: [1,2]
}
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="areas">
 <div id="gamearea">
  <div id="top1" class="top p1">Top</div><button id="deck1" class="deck p1" {{action 'drawCard'}}></button><div id="bot1" class="bot p1">Bot</div>
  <div id="lib1" class="zone display-zone p1 library">

  </div>
  
  {{game-zone cards=model.lib1}}
  {{game-zone cards=model.hand1}}
  
  
  <div id="hand1" class="zone display-zone p1 hand">
  </div>
  <div id="battlefield1" class="zone display-zone p1 battlefield"></div>
  <div id="graveyard1" class="zone display-zone p1 graveyard"></div>
  <div id="exile1" class="zone display-zone p1 exile"></div>
  <div id="revealed1" class="zone display-zone p1 revealed"></div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div id="top2" class="top p2">Top</div><div id="deck2" class="deck p2"></div><div id="bot2" class="bot p2">Bot</div>
  <div id="lib2" class="zone display-zone p2 library"></div>
  <div id="hand2" class="zone display-zone p2 hand"></div>
  <div id="battlefield2" class="xone display-zone p2 battlefield"></div>
  <div id="graveyard2" class="zone display-zone p2 graveyard"></div>
  <div id="exile2" class="zone display-zone p2 exile"></div>
  <div id="revealed2" class="zone display-zone p2 revealed"></div>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary menu-btn">Menu</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success to-top">To Top</button>
  
 </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/card-component">
 <img {{bind-attr id=card.domid alt=card.name src=card.img}} draggable="true" class="card" {{action "droppedCard" on="drop"}}>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/game-zone">
 {{#each card in cards}}
  {{card-component card=card}}
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: can you reproduce in a emberjs.jsbin.com ?

Comment: Sure thing.  That might be easier to work with.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jomema/1/edit?html,css,js,output is the jsbin... couldn't get it working, even to the level I have it locally since I couldn't find Ember data in the list of libraries you could include.  Either way, much appreciated.  Might see what I can do as far as workarounds are concerned...

Comment: You can just use one of the builds listed here http://emberjs.com/builds/#/tagged

Comment: done.  There are some minor naming differences between the code I have posted and the code in the jsbin... I'll be sticking with the code in the jsbin, as it's what I have here locally.

Comment: I am getting "home.game No model was found for 'card' Error: No model was found for 'card'" what exactly do I need to check in the jsbin?

Comment: Hmm.  That might be the problem.  I'll take a closer look when I'm in a position to.  I was never able to get Ember inspector or anything to throw an error when I visited the home.game route.

Comment: Cards are now rendering, and everything is running.  I copied and pasted the Card model I had.... it was a pluralization issue I think..  Thanks for the help.  Very much appreciated.  Like I said, probably something stupid.